# Post data to php register webpage

Tags: asp.net

I have a register page written in php.

I want to make a webpage in asp.net with the required information which must be sent to the php webpage in order to automatically create the account with the information received from the asp.net webpage post.

So I want to post the new information from the asp.net webpage to the php page.

The php register page looks like this:

```
<form action="" type=post>
      <label for="name"><div><br>Account</br></div></label> <input type=text id="name" name="account" size=20 maxlength=32 /><br>
       <label for="name"><div><br>Password</br></div></label> <input type=password id="name" name="password" size=20 maxlength=14 /><br> 
      <button type=submit>Okay</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: So, what do you want us to do?

Comment: To guide me a little. what I'm supposed to do in order to post the data to the other website

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a request from the asp.net page to the PHP page. You can either have your ASP.NET page fill the form and go the PHP url (if this is possible), or, you can have your backend in ASP.NET use an HTTP library or something to replicate the form onto the PHP side.

Comment: I did that , to go to the php url but if the account already exists I can't find that since I'm just executind the url

Comment: Okay, now  that's where you will need access to the PHP code. You need to setup another page that can tell you whether or not the account already exists. In fact, this would be easiest if you had access to the same database since you could just look that up within ASP.NET.

Comment: 1.I'm making a webrequest with the information I have chosen. and I don't want to open the php website because it must be hidden from the users 2.I can't check the database since there isn't . because the php file is creating files on the current dedicated server with the account name.txt

Comment: That's a horrible idea. Don't ever use flat files for storage. Please, please, please do everyone a favor and move to database. You don't have to *open* the PHP website to users, you just have to add a page that can give you back some JSON or XML or something on whether or not an account already exists.